# Missing angular.json file in nx workspace Angular project

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a css framework to my angular project that I recently started but I noticed I do not have an angular.json file. Should I be missing this or can I add a style reference somewhere else? [Here is my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nmbc.png)

Comment: You can use workspace.json

Comment: angular.json was removed since it no longer provides extra information. Add your css to the `project.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the style reference in the src/style.scss or CSS depending on your choice.

```
@import "xy.scss";
```